# how to get specific value from server response for uploaded file ajax

Tags: forms, node.js, upload, response

i have tried to send uploaded file to server by using ajax like this

```
    formData.append('foldername',fname);
    formData.append('file', file)
    $.ajax({

            url: 'imageupload',
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            type: 'POST',
            success:function(response)
            {


                            alert(response);
                            alert(response.imagename);


            }
    });
```

it is send data to server successfully but i have sent response from server like this

```
  res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'text/html', 'Access-Control-Allow-Orgin':'*'});
  res.write(JSON.stringify({"imagename":"1.jpeg","imageid":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}));
  res.end();
```

i have written two alert in success function . in first alert i got like this

{"imagename":"1.jpeg","imageid":"xxxxxxxxxxxx"}

i have written second alert for to get  imagename but i got undefine

so i could not get specific  key value. how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

change

```
res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'text/html', 'Access-Control-Allow-Orgin':'*'});
```

to

```
res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'application/json', 'Access-Control-Allow-Orgin':'*'});
```

jquery don't convert a `JSON string` to `Javascript Object` if the content type is `'Content-Type':'text/html'`. So, `'Content-Type':'application/json'` or `'Content-Type':'text/json'` will do the magic. You will get the response as Javascript object in the client. So, you can do

```
alert(response.imagename);//alerts image name
```